# How to disable redirects when doing a URLFetch in PHP for Google App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, redirect

I'm trying to set up two PHP on GAE sites: One to act as a web services layer, and another to act as the front-end. So far, things are great. I'm trying to secure communications between these two layers, so that not only I can call my web services.

I found this article that talks about making requests, and by doing so, it can set the **X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid** header, which is exactly what I want.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/#PHP_Making_requests

To do this, the article says I should "consider telling the UrlFetch service to not follow redirects when invoking it."; then promptly does not provide any documentation on how you actually **DO** that.

My request looks like this:

```
$data = ['data' => 'this', 'data2' => 'that'];
$data = http_build_query($data);
$context = [
    'http' => [
    'method' => 'get',
    'header' => "custom-header: custom-value\r\n" . "custom-header-two: custome-value-2\r\n",
    'content' => $data,
    ]
];
$context = stream_context_create($context);
$result = file_get_contents('urlgoeshere', false, $context);
```

Thoughts & help are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways, either set follow_location to false and/or max_redirects to 0.

```
$context = [
    'http' => [
    'method' => 'get',
    'header' => "custom-header: custom-value\r\n" . "custom-header-two: custome-value-2\r\n",
    'content' => $data,
    'follow_location' => false,
    ]
];
```

or

```
$context = [
    'http' => [
    'method' => 'get',
    'header' => "custom-header: custom-value\r\n" . "custom-header-two: custome-value-2\r\n",
    'content' => $data,
    'max_redirects' => 0,
    ]
];
```

Comment: I tried these, but it didn't seem to have any effect on the gae headers.

Comment: what header are you after?

Comment: **X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid**: A Google App Engine header when one app calls another. You're required to have redirection off. From the Google [Documentation](http://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/urlfetch/#PHP_Making_requests):

_If you are making requests to another App Engine app, you should consider telling the UrlFetch service to not follow redirects when invoking it.

This setting does two things:

Makes your calls faster
Adds an X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid header containing your app ID to the request, so the responding app can determine the source of incoming requests._

Comment: Ahh so you need to remember that PHP changes headers to start with HTTP and replaces '-' with '_' so you need to check for $_SERVER["HTTP_X_APPENGINE_INBOUND_APPID"] which is correctly filled in when follow_location set to false.

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me through this.

I've created a page here, that shows headers that start with HTTP_: http://ws.dracosoftware.com/

You can call directly, and see browser-source headers. Then, I created a page on an existing app, which calls the above URL and shows the contents of the service:
http://www.dracosoftware.com/test.php

The options used on that page are:
$options2 = [
    'http' => [
        'method' => 'get',
        'header' => "foo: bar2",
        'follow_location' => false,
        'max_redirects' => 0,
    ]
];

No inbound header. Ideas?

Comment: I did the same thing to test before I posted above :) http://1.hackit-app-1.appspot.com/test.php makes a URL fetch call to  php-minishell.appspot.com/phpinfo and echos the result. Scroll to the bottom you'll see _SERVER["HTTP_X_APPENGINE_INBOUND_APPID"] = hackit-app-1

Comment: Ok it works if I call your app directly, but fails if I call it through you custom domain (Try http://1.hackit-app-1.appspot.com/test1.php). Looks like a bug - can you file it in the issue tracker.